# Git Push Error on RPC Failed

Tags: git, repository, push, rpc

I was trying to push to a repository that I just cloned. Now, I can't push because of this error:

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I reinstalled Git, but it's still the same. I also tried increasing the httpBuffer but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No. I am not behind a proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 401 when pushing to Git (GitLab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169252/error-401-when-pushing-to-git-gitlab)